# SQL Server compare amount with date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

all, I need help about my works

I have to compare data between current month and previous month and also with date and day range. I have amount in current month (December) between 1st December and 3rd December. 1st December is on Wednesday, 2nd December is on Thursday, and 3rd December is on Friday. 1st December until 3rd December is the first week on December. The previous month, first week on November, Wednesday until Friday is on 3rd, 4th and 5th November.

How can I perform this in SQL Server?

What I've tried is looked like this:

```
select * 
from (
    -- Current Month
    SELECT Businessday, Amount, datename(dw,BusinessDay) AS DaysName,
    DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, BusinessDay), 0), BusinessDay) +1 AS WeekNumber
    FROM TableTransaction
    WHERE Businessday BETWEEN '2021-12-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-12-03 00:00:00.000'
) x left join (
    -- Previous Month
    SELECT Businessday, Amount, datename(dw,BusinessDay) AS DaysName,
    DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, BusinessDay), 0), BusinessDay) +1 AS WeekNumber
    FROM TableTransaction
    WHERE Businessday BETWEEN '2021-11-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2021-11-30 00:00:00.000'
) y on x.DaysName = y.DaysName AND x.WeekNumber = y.WeekNumber
```

Another thought is, How if range date which I chose is 23th December until 30th December which is Thursday in fourth week, the previous month is (Thursday in fourth week) the range is until first week of December, how can I perform this?

Your answer will be so helpful.

Comment: Have you considered using [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts Actually I haven't used it before, I will read it first, thank you

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic Actually my expected output is how I get amount from previous month with same day and same weeks, Example, I have an amount on Wednesday on first week of December and I want to do the same on Wednesday on first week of November.